# Swift-function, which checks if all letters in a string are unique

Tags: strings, swift

The task is writing a function, which checks if a string contains only unique characters. Means: is each character is included only one time.

Here's the solution, I have developed:

```
func areAllLettersUnique(_ str: String) -> Bool {
    let arr = str.split(separator: "")
    for (i, chr) in arr.enumerated() {
        if arr[i + 1..<arr.count].contains(chr) {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return true
}

assert(areAllLettersUnique("No duplicates") == true, "Challenge 1.1 failed")
assert(areAllLettersUnique("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") == true, "Challenge 1.2 failed")
assert(areAllLettersUnique("AaBbCc") == true, "Challenge 1.3 failed")
assert(areAllLettersUnique("Hello, world") == false, "Challenge 1.4 failed")
print("All assertions successful")
```

It has passed the provided asserts and I think it works correct.

But: **Is there a better, perhaps more "swifty" solution?**

**Can I expect my code to work correctly or are there flaws?**

Comment: Not familiar with swift, but generally if you make a Set from the string, and compare its length with the original strings length, you get the answer without (explicit) iteration.

Comment: @morbusg Great idea. Thanks.

Comment: @morbusg Works perfectly fine. I tried it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
let arr = str.split(separator: "")
```

creates an array of one-element substrings of the original string. It is simpler to create an array of `Character`s with

```
let arr = Array(str)
```

It might also be a bit more efficient to compare characters instead of substrings. Also this works not only for strings but for arbitrary `Sequence`s.

```
if arr[i + 1..<arr.count].contains(chr)
```

can be simplified slightly using a [RangeExpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangeexpression), in this case `...`

```
if arr[(i + 1)...].contains(chr)
```

The variable name `arr` does not indicate what it contains, a better choice might be something like `allCharacters`.

---

Your method is not very efficient, the complexity is \$ O(N^2) \$ where \$ N \$ is the length of the string.

One can use a `Set` to store the distinct characters of the string. A very short and simple implementation would be

```
func areAllLettersUnique(_ str: String) -> Bool {
    let allCharacters = Set(str)
    return allCharacters.count == str.count
}
```

but this does not [“short-circuit”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): The entire string is processed even if a duplicate character has been found.

But one can enumerate the characters and keep track of all characters seen to far:

```
func areAllLettersUnique(_ str: String) -> Bool {
    var charactersSeenSoFar = Set<Character>()
    for chr in str {
        if charactersSeenSoFar.contains(chr) {
            return false
        }
        charactersSeenSoFar.insert(chr)
    }
    return true
}
```

The `insert` operation of a `Set` returns a value which indicates whether the element was newly inserted or already present, so this can be further simplified to

```
func areAllLettersUnique(_ str: String) -> Bool {
    var charactersSeenSoFar = Set<Character>()
    for chr in str {
        if !charactersSeenSoFar.insert(chr).inserted {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Finally note that this method can be made *generic* with minor changes, so that it can be used with arbitrary sequences of (hashable) elements

```
func areAllElementsUnique<C>(_ seq: C) -> Bool
where C: Sequence, C.Element: Hashable
{
    var elementsSeenSoFar = Set<C.Element>()
    for elem in seq {
        if !elementsSeenSoFar.insert(elem).inserted {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Addendum: There is a trivial case where the length of the string is greater than the considered alphabet size

Comment: @ielyamani: Sure, that might be useful in programming contests where a restriction on the alphabet it given, e.g. only latin characters. – For a general purpose routine that might not be relevant, a Swift `String` is a collection of “extended grapheme clusters” and the Unicode Standard contains [149,186 characters](https://unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html)